How to Manage Auth.js (NextAuth v5) Sessions in the Root Layout with App Router?
I’m a bit confused about managing sessions correctly in Next.js 14 using the App Router. Currently, I’m fetching the session in every page.ts like this:
const session = await auth();
When I need the session in a client component, I pass it as a prop.
However, I have a header component within my layout.ts that also requires the session.
I don’t want to call  await auth(); again in the layout because that would mean fetching the session on the layout.ts and then on the page.ts ?
My question is: is it possible to fetch the session once in the layout and share it across all pages using that layout?
Or am I required to include the header in every page and not using session in the layout ?
How can I handle this issue efficiently?
Thanks, everyone!

you can cache this in next await auth(); where it wont de-duplicate. will that solve your issue
